Compute normal vector at a specific point of a svg path pointing outwards
I'm trying to make a physics engine in javascript using not the usual canvas with vertices but instead used only svgs, and i've reached a point where I need to compute the normal vector at the collision point which is quite easy using this piece of code:
let dx = 0.001;
let after = a.getPointAtLength(i + dx).matrixTransform(a.getScreenCTM())
let before = a.getPointAtLength(i - dx).matrixTransform(a.getScreenCTM())
arr.push({x: -after.y + before.y, y: after.x - before.x});  // Push normal vector

The only problem is, that I need the vector pointing out of the shape. What would be the fastest way to check whether I should inverse the vector or not?
As an example this is a normal vector I obtained, which is not the one I desired:


the shapes can be any svg component, including paths or text elements

but they need to be closed

Please, add a minimal reproducible example – ideally a snippet. Also, please illustrate which points/values you're trying to retrieve. Showing us an undesired result is rather confusing. Quite likely you can find suitable methods in bezier.js

Are you sure you have to invert the normal, not shift it away from origin? check if normal is always from origin(bottom right) or varies and say
